# Part of viewpager above screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, android-viewpager

As I'm quite new to java I'm not sure if this is possible, so I ask you for help. I'm wondering if it is possible to have part of a viewpager hidden above the screen/under the action bar. I have attached an image for illustration.

What I want is for part of the viewpager to be above the actual screen, part of it shown and part of it under the rest of the layout. Reason behind this is that I want it to slide down and cover the whole screen when the user slides down (white layout slides down and out).

Is this possible? If so, could you give me any pointers to how. Thanks in advance.
[image: Layout illustration]

Comment: negative top margin on the viewpager